# jQuery UI Draggable set drag size

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I have a number of small icons which are draggable via jQuery which i clone, can i make the draggable icon larger when drag starts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) using the [`start`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-start) and [`stop`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop) events, something like this:

```
$(".icon").draggable({
    start: function() {
        $(this).height(100).width(100);   //drag dimensions
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).height(50).width(50);     //original icon size
    }
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8QteZ/), or [a bit more compact](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8QteZ/1/):

```
$(".icon").draggable({
    start: function() {
        $(this).css({ height: 100, width: 100 });
    },
    stop: function() {
        $(this).css({ height: 50, width: 50 });
    }
});​
```

Comment: That is sooo cool, thx. One last question. I want to leave the original icon in place with the original dimensions?

Comment: @Dooie - You can set the `helper: 'clone'` option, is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8QteZ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Bind events to dragstart and dragend, see sample here:
[Active Drag Demo (number 5)](http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drag/)

And addClass() when dragging start with styles that couse image will be bigger, and removeClass() when drag stops.

Comment: This is a different dragging library, the OP is referring specifically jQuery UI Draggable, found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/